# Why does the test runner stop in the middle of these JUnit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Working on a Java project, there are 670 JUnit tests in one module. After a recent refactoring, a strange behavior appeared.

What's happening is, despite the fact that all 670 tests run and pass OK when I attempt to run all tests in the module (JUnit test runner recognizes the correct number of tests, and begins running them), it just *stops* after test 187:

[image: Stopped. Tests passed: 187 of 670 tests]

I removed all the tests and added them back in, groups at a time, searching for an offending test. Also, I tried different combinations of tests, to see if a particular test(s) derail the test suite. Strangely, any 600 tests run all the way through:

[image: Tests passed: 600 of 600 tests]

601 tests and the suite stops running after test 205:

[image: Stopped. Tests passed: 205 of 601 tests]

Then, as I add more tests, the number at which it stops regresses, to that 187 of 670 number we see in the first of my three screenshots.

Approximately 150 of these tests are integration tests which rely on connections to resources, whereas the remaining majority of tests are unit tests. I suspect that these resource connections are a factor, allowing the same number of tests to pass *or* fail, depending on the number of them that are integration tests.

Turns out, **I can click "Rerun failed tests" and it functions as a "continue running test suite" button.** After that two-step process, I'm able to run the entire suite, all green.

To confirm it's the result of an actual change in my codebase, and not the result of cache invalidation, I went so far as to delete all IDE-related files, check it out and build it on a fresh machine with all new OS and tools. Yet, only the refactored branch now consistently exhibits this strange behavior.

Comment: Can you figure out which test it runs last, and maybe step through it? I think a `System.exit` call might do that (I just tried it, and that's the behavior on my machine).

Comment: I tried many different combinations of tests, and it turns out, no particular test can be blamed.

Comment: It could be that you have some static state somewhere, such that test B hits a System.exit but only if test A runs before it.

Comment: I think you nailed it. An integration test support class was opening SQL connections without closing them, and when it got to the magic number and got its connection denied, that test class did in fact System.exit()

Comment: Oof, those kinds of bugs are a pain to track down. Glad you found it!